# Specifying an SRS in a WFS input for a WPS operation in GeoServer

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, wfs, wps

I am currently trying to perform a custom WPS operation on a set of filtered vectors in GeoServer. My plan is to specify the operation's input using a WFS query, which provides the flexibility I need to filter my layer's data. However, I stumbled upon an unexpected behavior regarding the projection management.

Let's say I want to fetch all vectors from a layer that intersects a polygon. My data is stored on GeoServer with an *EPSG:3944* projection, whereas my client uses *EPSG:900913*, so I have to make sure GeoServer transforms the polygon's coordinates correctly before filtering. Here is the summary of my experiments:

1. Making a simple WFS query with the `intersects` filter and the appropriate `srsName="EPSG:900913"` attribute works as expected. I get 196 features as a result.
2. Making a WPS request (execute `vec:Count` to keep it simple), with the same WFS request made in *1.* as the input, yields a result of **0** (of course I expected **196**)
3. Making the same WPS request than in *2.*, but removing the `srsName` attribute from the WFS part, and sending *EPSG:3944* coordinates instead of *EPSG:900913*, does return **196**.

This leads me to think that I should maybe specify my `srsName` elsewhere when doing a WPS request (or maybe there's a bug that ignores `srsName` while inside a WPS input ?). If someone has a hint to solve this problem so I don't have to manually translate my coordinates on the client it would be great!

---

### Technical details if needed

Software versions used :

- GeoServer 2.13.2
- WPS extension (gs-wps-core) 2.13.2

For reference, the full WFS and WPS requests mentioned above are :

1:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetFeature xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" outputFormat="GML2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Query typeName="test:test_vectors" srsName="EPSG:900913">
        <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <Intersects>
                <PropertyName>GEOMETRY</PropertyName>
                <Polygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
                    <exterior>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <posList srsDimension="2">597580.1398002531 5356306.963293549 598602.4850535673 5356330.849864888 598612.039682103 5355748.0175242135 596629.4542609563 5355810.122609695 597580.1398002531 5356306.963293549</posList>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </exterior>
                </Polygon>
            </Intersects>
        </Filter>
    </Query>
</GetFeature>
```

2:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>vec:Count</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
            <GetFeature xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" outputFormat="GML2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <Query typeName="test:test_vectors" srsName="EPSG:900913">
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:Intersects>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>GEOMETRY</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <gml:Polygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
                                <gml:exterior>
                                    <gml:LinearRing>
                                        <gml:posList srsDimension="2">597580.1398002531 5356306.963293549 598602.4850535673 5356330.849864888 598612.039682103 5355748.0175242135 596629.4542609563 5355810.122609695 597580.1398002531 5356306.963293549</gml:posList>
                                    </gml:LinearRing>
                                </gml:exterior>
                            </gml:Polygon>
                        </ogc:Intersects>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                </Query>
            </GetFeature>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput>
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

3:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>vec:Count</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
            <GetFeature xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" outputFormat="GML2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <Query typeName="test:test_vectors">
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:Intersects>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>GEOMETRY</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <gml:Polygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
                                <gml:exterior>
                                    <gml:LinearRing>
                                        <gml:posList srsDimension="2">1892160.95123831 3123943.84329389 1892905.46022422 3123982.62653498 1892924.62569713 3123559.6021486 1891478.48475506 3123563.1983795 1892160.95123831 3123943.84329389</gml:posList>
                                    </gml:LinearRing>
                                </gml:exterior>
                            </gml:Polygon>
                        </ogc:Intersects>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                </Query>
            </GetFeature>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput>
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```